# Using powershell to read a file and split the text, but its throwing an error

Tags: powershell

I've written a powershell script to scan the network, and put those results into a file, sort and edit those results.

I can do all of that, except some of the pc names are coming back as NAME.DOMAIN.COM and others are just NAME, so I want to split the text, and just get the NAME.

However I'm getting this error for each line in the file:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListV2.ps1:31 char:25
+ $text | Foreach-Object {$_.PCCOMPUTERNAMES.split(".")[0]} | Out-File  ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Here is my script:

```
[System.Console]::Clear();
#Delete old output file
Write-Output "Removing old output file"
Remove-Item C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListSorted.txt
#Declare IP range
$range = 1..254
$address = "192.168.0."
#status
Write-Output "Scanning active PCs"
#Scan ip range and get pc names
$range | 
ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Progress 'Scanning Network' $address$_ -PercentComplete (($_ / $range.Count) * 100) 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    Get-WmiObject Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='192.168.0.$_' and Timeout=200 and ResolveAddressNames='true' and StatusCode=0"  | 
    Select-Object -Property @{Name="PCCOMPUTERNAMES";Expression={ [Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress($_.Address).HostName+'.'  }} 
} | Out-File C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerList.txt
#Sort list
Write-Output "Sort list"
Get-Content -Path C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerList.txt | Sort-Object -Unique | Out-File C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListRaw.txt
#Edit work file
Get-Content -Path C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListRaw.txt | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Out-File C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListEdited.txt
$text = Import-Csv C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListEdited.txt
$text | Foreach-Object {$_.PCCOMPUTERNAMES.split(".")[0]} | Out-File C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListEdited2.txt
#Rename file
Rename-Item -Path "C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListEdited2.txt" -NewName "C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListSorted.txt"
#Delete old output file
Write-Output "Removing work files"
Remove-Item C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerList.txt
Remove-Item C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListRaw.txt
#Final statement
Write-Output "Final list in ComputerListSorted.txt"
```

Here is my sample file ComputerListEdited.txt:

```
NAME1.
NAME2.DOMAIN.COM
NAME3
NAME4
NAME5.DOMAIN.COM
```

Comment: From your sample, "ComputerListEdited.txt" isn't a CSV file, but in code you treat it as one, using `Import-Csv`. This can't work. Use `Get-Content` instead.

Comment: Tried that, still getting the error message.

Comment: so you are pinging every machine from 192.168.1.1 thru 192.168.1.254 
are you on a network that has all 254 ips taken, what does it show when you just ping a blank ip that is not being used. might need to add a catch for if nothing is found.

Comment: Its only throwing the error for the number of names it finds.  So its generating the file fine with the input, but the error is on the split code.

Comment: Is it because I'm losing my property in between files?

Comment: I would refactor this script to get rid of the temporary files, which complicate the script unneccessarily. E. g. instead of `... | Out-File C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerList.txt` you assign the output of the loop to a variable: `$computerList = $range | ForEach-Object { ... }`. Then you can do further processing of this variable: `$sortedComputerList = $computerList | Sort-Object -Unique` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As zett42 mentioned, your "Import-CSV" function is likely the cause. Running the same code on my computer outputs the error

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At line:1 char:25
>
> - $text | Foreach-Object {$_.PCCOMPUTERNAMES.split(".")[0]} | Out-File  ...
> - ```
>                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

This is because using "Import-CSV" makes PowerShell treat the first line as the header.

```
NAME1.
-----
NAME2.DOMAIN.COM
NAME3
NAME4
NAME5.DOMAIN.COM
```

As the first line is "Name1.", this is the header value for the column of computer names. (Unfortunately, this means it is skipping the first computer as well). Changing this to `Get-Content` resolves this problem.

Additionally, you're referring to the columns as if they have a header `PCCOMPUTERNAMES`, which doesn't exist. Remove this reference as well to fix the problem. Try the below in its place.

```
$text = Get-Content C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListEdited.txt
$text | Foreach-Object {$_.split(".")[0]} | Out-File C:\PowershellScripts\ComputerListEdited2.txt
```

A side note as well, you're getting info, exporting to a text file, then reading the text file, then deleting the text file. Keeping this information in a variable inside the script could lead to slightly better performance.